# C# serialize json from Twitter without data member

Tags: c#, json, serialization, twitter

I'm working on my own small Twitter application in C#.
I've managed to serialize the json data from https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=
It returns something like this:

```
{ "ids" : [ 401295021,
  506271294,
  14405250,
  25873220
],
"next_cursor" : 0,
"next_cursor_str" : "0",
"previous_cursor" : 0,
"previous_cursor_str" : "0"
}
```

Using this class I can serialize it:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class TwitterFollowers
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "ids")]
        public IList<int> AccountIDs { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to get the screen names of the followers so I use this url:
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=

This json looks like this:

```
[ { "contributors_enabled" : false,
"created_at" : "Wed Apr 16 06:30:52 +0000 2008",
"default_profile" : false,
"default_profile_image" : false,
"description" : "",
"utc_offset" : -25200,
"verified" : false
},
{ "contributors_enabled" : false,
"created_at" : "Tue Mar 04 12:31:57 +0000 2008",
"default_profile" : true,
"default_profile_image" : false,
"description" : "",
"utc_offset" : 3600,
"verified" : false
}
]
```

As you can see the array starts right away, without naming it.
How should my class look like to serialize this?

I've tried this, but that doesn't work:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class TwitterProfiles
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "")]
        public IList<TwitterProfile> Profiles { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class TwitterProfile
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "lang")]
        public string Language { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "location")]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "screen_name")]
        public string ScreenName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "url")]
        public string URL { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried just removing the "Name" property off the DataMember attribute all together? Meaning, [DataMember] public IList<TwitterProfile> Profiles { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing the "Name" property off of the DataMember attribute all together? Meaning:

```
[DataMember]
public IList<TwitterProfile> Profiles { get; set; }
```

If that doesn't work, one option you could also do is grab the output from the api call, and format it into a json string that you know you can deserialize:

```
string.Format("{{\"profiles\":{0}}}", GetJsonResponse())
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample you've provided doesn't match the members of the class `TwitterProfile`. Notwithstanding this, you don't need a helper class to handle an array. You can simply target the array type directly at deserialization.

Here's a code sample that you can use to test. I've removed your `TwitterProfiles` class and stripped down `TwitterProfile` to just a field named `CreatedAt`.

Note the following line in the source below:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer js = 
    new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TwitterProfile[]));
```

Here is the rest.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace TwProfileJson
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) { return; }
            string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(dlg.FileName);

            using(MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TwitterProfile[]));
                TwitterProfile[] pps = (TwitterProfile[])js.ReadObject(stm);

                foreach(TwitterProfile p in pps)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.CreatedAt);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class TwitterProfile
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "created_at")]
            public string CreatedAt { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```